# Error in subscribing to webhook message in messenger setting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, my facebook develop app has basic permissions to reply to comments (pages_manage_engagement) or to text (pages_messaging). However, I have a problem when subscribing to webhook messages, where messages get unsubscribed after 1-2 minutes. Will I have a problem or is my app missing some permissions?

Thank for help.

[image]

I tried subscribing directly on my app in the FB develop web, and tried running the api [https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/{{page_id}}/subscribed_apps?access_token={{access_token}}](https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/%7B%7Bpage_id%7D%7D/subscribed_apps?access_token=%7B%7Baccess_token%7D%7D) with subscribed_fields=feed, mention, name, picture, category, description, conversations, messages, it just got me I can receive messages from messenger for 1-2', then I can't receive anymore.

Comment: Facebook will unsubscribe your app from a webhook, if your app repeatedly fails to respond with 200 OK, within 5 or less seconds.

Comment: @CBroe About 1 week ago, I still can do it normally, it just happened in the last few days